# Duplicate images on upload

Tags: images, duplicates

i have the problem with wordpress when i upload 1 image is making 7 images with 7 sizes i want to have only 1 image to stop making from 1 image 7 images with different sizes.
Thank you!

Comment: WP does this so that it doesn't have to auto-resize things on the fly which would be super slow/expensive. It's how small/medium/large images work. Plugins register additional sizes, eliminating this will have major performance hits on the frontend, and can cause broken layouts, and other problems

Comment: solved, i found a plugin which stop making thumbnails. thank you!